# how to configure solr on my web?

Tags: solr

I am using apache-tomcat. My solr works fine on my localhost.Now I want to put it online.In apache-tomcat,In my bin folder i put my solr dir.But online, I do not have any bin folder.so can anyone tell me how to configure solr in my web host dir.thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

First you secure your entire tomcat web admin gui by requiring authentication. First, create a new user in /etc/tomcat6/tomcat-users.xml

```
<tomcat-users>
  <role rolename="admin"/>
  <role rolename="manager"/>
  <role rolename="proxyUsers"/>
  <user username="jorno" password="XXXXX" roles="admin,manager,proxyUsers"/>
  <user username="proxyUser" password="XXXXXX" roles="proxyUsers"/>
</tomcat-users>
```

Add the security constraint in the file /etc/tomcat6/web.xml

```
<security-constraint>
    <web-resource-collection>
      <web-resource-name>
        Solr authenticated application
      </web-resource-name>

      <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
      <http-method>GET</http-method>
      <http-method>POST</http-method>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <auth-constraint>
      <role-name>solrUsers</role-name>
    </auth-constraint>
  </security-constraint>
   <login-config>
    <auth-method>BASIC</auth-method>
    <realm-name>Basic Authentication</realm-name>
  </login-config>
  <security-role>
    <description>solr users</description>
  </security-role>
```

Remember to restart tomcat

```
/etc/init.d/tomcat6 restart
```

Visit your tomcat solr application web gui and check that the authentication works.

Now we create the actual proxy in apache. First, create a simple site. PHP is required. The following example vhost will do the trick. Notice the rewrite.

q.example.com - Solr search engine proxy

```
<VirtualHost *>
        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        DocumentRoot /var/www/q.example.com
        ServerName q.example.com
        ServerAlias solr.example.com

        AddDefaultCharset UTF-8

        ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/error.log

        # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
        # alert, emerg.
        LogLevel warn

        CustomLog /var/log/apache2/access.log combined
        ServerSignature On

        # REWRITES
        RewriteEngine on
        # Debug:
        # RewriteLog /tmp/rwlog
        # RewriteLogLevel 9

        RewriteRule ^/([^/]+)/?                 /index.php                    [NC,L]

</VirtualHost>
```

Remember to reload apache

```
/etc/init.d/apache2 reload
```

Now create an index.php file in the root of the site. Depending on how often you update your index you might want to let the user cache the contents of the proxy. I’ve set 5 minutes here.

```
<?php

// Avvoid too long client cache
// calc an offset of 5 minutes
$offset = 60 * 5;
// calc the string in GMT not localtime and add the offset
$expire = "Expires: " . gmdate("D, d M Y H:i:s", time() + $offset) . " GMT";
//output the HTTP header
Header($expire);

// Write the result from solr
Echo file_get_contents('http://proxyUser:[password]@127.0.0.1:8080/solr/select?'.$_SERVER["QUERY_STRING"]);

?>
```

That’s pretty much it. You can now test the proxy like so

http://q.example.com/select?q=*%3A*&indent=on